# I have a qustion in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to insert path of a file in mysql?

If we use varchar only then it omits the backslashes like if path is C:\Users\ABC
then it removes the slashes and stores it like C:UsersABC.

How to solve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! This question does not seem to be about Ubuntu, and as such, it's off-topic here, as per our [help]. I would suggest you ask on [dba.SE] if you still need help with this issue.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [SO] or maybe [DBA.SE].

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as the following -

> C:\\Users\\ABC

You need to escape this backslashes (with another backslash), to make them appear. So, if you use double quotes, write `\\` instead of just `\`, or use `addslashes($url)`.